# Houses, Flats, Shops comes in which category?

Tags: word-request, nouns

I'm building an application for managing Rent for houses, flats and shops and I came to point where I wanted to give the Main Menu a name.

I named it "residentials" at first, but it seemed to me "residentials" are only places where people live, shops are for work, so shops might not come into the category of "Residentials".

So next thing I thought about was "Property", but I am not sure about that too.

I am not good with English, what name should I give to this category and the website name also depends on it.

Answer (score 3):

You could name it "Property for Rent", or simply "Property" would do. You could also name your category "Property for [Lease](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lease)"

Answer (score 1):

I work with an IT company that makes mobile apps. I often suggest 'menu names' for applications. I **agree** with the term *property*. Another option for the menu button's text is - *assets*. The dropdown menu can then contain all your titles *Shop, flats, penthouses* and the like.

Though the term extends its meaning to other things (machinery, for instance) as well but when used in a mobile app for managing rent is concerned, it'll convey the message. Simply *Choose your asset/property* and then listing down those entities would serve the purpose.

I don't think the website's name has to match with the main menu on the app. Both are entirely different. What matters is the *name of the app* and the *name of the website*.

Answer (score 0):

If the house, flat, shop or whatever is a person's property you could name the category **"[Property](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/property)"**

You could call it "**Rentals**" in North America it means *"a rented house or car"*

You can say **"Rental Property"** or **"Property for Rent"**

> "**Assets**" as @MaulikV suggested is a good choice too.

"**Holdings**" is almost like **asset** and can also be what you're looking for.